# PHP autoload fails to find class files after AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm building a very simple shop app using PHP and some JQuery.
On the first load, the app loads fine, but if do GET request call to the same script, it gives me an error:

```
Warning: require(app\controllers\Wallet.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc\app\core\autoload.php on line 5
```

Here's my `index.php` file (Bootstrap and Jquery links omitted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>MyShop</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
    <?php 
        require_once 'app/core/App.php';
    ?>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my `app/core/App.php`:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

require_once 'autoload.php';

//Instantiate
$wallet = new Wallet();
$header = new Header();
$products = new Products();
$products_list = $products->getProducts();
$cart = new Cart($products_list);
//Do logic
$cart->addToCart(2);

if(isset($_GET['addtocart']))
{
    $added_id = $_GET['addtocart'];
    $cart->addToCart($added_id);
}
if(isset($_GET['removefromcart']))
{
    $added_id = $_GET['removefromcart'];
    $cart->removeFromCart($added_id);
}
if(isset($_GET['checkout']))
{
    $cart->checkout();
}

//
//Show everything
$header->showHeader($wallet);
$products->showProducts();
$cart->showCart();
```

Autoload in `autoload.php` is very simple

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function($className)
{  
   require $className.'.php';
});
```

And here's example of a jquery script tied to `Add to cart` button:

```
$(function() {
    $('#app').on("click","#addtocart", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        productId = $(e.target).data("product-id")
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: './app/core/App.php',
            data: {
                'addtocart': productId,
            },
            success: results => {
                $('#app').html(results);
            },
            error: () => {
                alert('Load error');
            }
        });
        console.log(productId);
    });    
})
```

Seems like nothing changes, but the code breaks.

Comment: You are missing `?>` in autoload.php and app/core/App.php.

Comment: @CoderCharmander, unfortunately, fixing that doesn't help. 
The point is that at first load it works, and on AJAX call it fails.

Comment: Are the other PHP files in app/controllers? (I know this is a stupid recommendation)

Comment: @CoderCharmander yes, sure. All the necessary files are there. And they do get included in the first load. 
I think there's something that has to do with relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

Had to refactor `autoload.php` adding absolute path to make it work:

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function($className)
{  
    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].PROJECT_SUBFOLDER.$className.'.php';
    if(file_exists($file))
    {
        require_once $file;
    }
    else {
        echo 'File:'.$file.' not found';
    }
});

?>
```